# How to change the selected and unselected segment's colour in UISegmentedcontrol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

[I want the UISegmentedcontrol like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osR4Z.png)

I would like to change the selected and unselected segment's color.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's likely to be a custom subclass of `NSView`

Comment: I want the selected segments colour to be lightBlue and unselected segments in darkBlue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
self.segmantControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:114.0/255. green:197./255. blue:182./255. alpha:1.0];
```

---

// if u haven't got constraints in IB/storyboard, u should set height constraint programmaticly

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.segmantControl
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             multiplier:1
                                                               constant:55];
[self.segmantControl addConstraint:constraint];
```

// if u have constraints in IB/storyboard, u should set property to height constraint with name (segmentHeight)

```
self.segmentHeight.constant = 55; // height constraint, U should add constraints to your segment control and set property to height constraint, and change it
```

---

```
self.segmantControl.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;
self.segmantControl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.segmantControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.segmantControl.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

// color selected text ---> whiteColor
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] } forState:UIControlStateSelected];
// color disabled text ---> whiteColor
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIColor *newSelectedTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:109./255. green:175./255. blue:179./255 alpha:1.0];
[[[self.segmantControl subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];//selected left segment color
[[[self.segmantControl subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];// selected right segment colour
```

result:
[image]

Comment: yellow background doesn't show up.. when it loads,it shows red colour but the next segment's background is blank.I need colour for that background too.. ie unselected one's.

Comment: @AkhilJiji, nice, copy and past my code, and don't remember about constraints

Comment: Well can you tell me how to set this ? "self.segmentedToggle.constant = 55;" .Am getting error like "property contant not found on object of type UISegmentedControl"

Comment: @AkhilJiji, hey self.segmentedToggle.constant - is not worked! in my code U can see self.segmentHeight.constant = 55, segmentHeight - is a property to height constraint, do u now haw to use constraints?

Comment: eventhough i added your code with NsLayout,the height still remains the same.

Comment: CGRect frame= _segmentedToggle.frame;
    [_segmentedToggle setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, 55)];   ....  This code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColour greenColor];
```

Once after clicking on any segment, Change color of selected segment:

```
- (void)selectedSegment:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    for (int i=0; i<[sender.subviews count]; i++) 
{
        if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected]) 
{
    UIColor *tintcolor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
}
 else 
{
            [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:nil];
        }
    }
}
```